# Why Visual Studio Code Not Run The Angular Project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

ng : File C:\Users\india\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\india\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser